# How to Call Navigation Drawer Fragment from Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer which is created by Android studio. I Called a Activity from the Navigation Drawer.In that Activity, the navigation drawer is not showing up ?
How can i Call the Navigation Drawer from the below Activity ?

**PlayerActivity**

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer;

public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER = 1;
private static final int REQ_RESOLVE_SERVICE_MISSING = 2;

private static final String PLAYLIST_ID = "PL5BxbbBpI7r";
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIwXEZQLS-U";

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private CharSequence mTitle;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
}

public void Play(View v) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    int startTimeMillis = 0;
    boolean autoplay = true;
    boolean lightboxMode = false;

    Intent intent = null;
    intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createPlaylistIntent(this, DEVELOPER_KEY,
            PLAYLIST_ID, startIndex, startTimeMillis, autoplay, lightboxMode);

    if (intent != null) {
        if (canResolveIntent(intent)) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER);
        } else {
            // Could not resolve the intent - must need to install or update the YouTube API service.
            YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_MISSING
                    .getErrorDialog(this, REQ_RESOLVE_SERVICE_MISSING).show();
        }
    }
}

private boolean canResolveIntent(Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    return resolveInfo != null && !resolveInfo.isEmpty();
}
```

}

**Navigation.java**

```
public class Navigation extends Activity
        implements HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, NewsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

   private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
   private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
         mTitle = getTitle();
        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, HomeFragment.newInstance("",""))
                .commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, NewsFragment.newInstance("",""))
                .commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent intent= new Intent(this,PlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                   break;

        }

    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((Navigation) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationDrawer` is meant to work with fragments, because the drawer is a fragment itself. You can access that drawer as long as you stay in the same `Activity` but once you change `Activity` you can't access to the drawer (Unless you create another instance of the drawer, but then you are missing the whole point of it). In order to accomplish what you want I'd recommend two things.

1) Instead of launching a new `Activity` make `PlayerActivity` a fragment.

2) Create a BaseActivity with a drawer and make all your other Activities extend it, that way you only have one single reference to the drawer in your project.

Comment: I can't Change the Player Activity into a fragment because it is using Youtube API.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragment instead of activity! You should have two fragments as default when you create the project. One is for navigation drawer, and the other one is for content. You should replace that content fragment with your new content which you put in second activity..

Comment: I haven't Created this project. Android studio itself Created this Navigation Drawer Project from Template.

Comment: I can't Change the Player Activity into a fragment because it is using Youtube API.

Comment: use YouTubePlayerFragment for Youtube API https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the same thing in the `PlayerActivity`

```
   mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
         mTitle = getTitle();
        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

Also put navigation drawer inside `R.layout.activity_player`.

Like you did in `R.layout.activity_navigation`